# Codeigniter 4 mssql query does not work completely

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter-4

I wrote a `MSSQL` query with `codeigniter` and ran it. Let me explain the `MSSQL` code.

1-> There are `10000-50000` records in the `json` array.

2-> updates these records if they exist or adds them.

3-> logs the additions and updates made.

After copying the dynamically generated code in `php`, I paste and run it in `sql` management. There is no problem. But when I run the query in `php`, it throws `141` records at most.

What could be the reason for this?

PHP code:

```
return $this->db->query($query);
```

MSSQL Code:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[ {"ad": "ali","soyad": "veli","tckimlikno": "12345785433" }]';

Declare @Count int Declare @EmpId bigint Declare @NewData nvarchar(MAX) Declare @Name NVARCHAR(MAX) Declare @Surname NVARCHAR(MAX) Declare @IdentificationNumber NVARCHAR(MAX)
INSERT INTO Logs (Type,ProcessTime,EmployeeID,UserId,NewData,Description )
VALUES ('Import Excel', getdate(), NULL, 1, @json, 'All Data');
Declare JsonTable Cursor Local For
select * from OPENJSON(@json) WITH (Name NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.ad',Surname NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.soyad',IdentificationNumber NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.tckimlikno' ) Open JsonTable Fetch Next
From JsonTable Into @Name, @Surname, @IdentificationNumber While @ @FETCH_STATUS = 0 Begin BEGIN TRY
SET @EmpId = NULL;
set @Count = (Select    count(*)From    EmployeeWHERE    IdentificationNumber = @IdentificationNumber );
IF @Count > 0 BEGIN
UPDATE Employee
SET Name = @Name, Surname = @Surname, IdentificationNumber = @IdentificationNumber
WHERE IdentificationNumber = @IdentificationNumber;
END
ELSE BEGIN
INSERT INTO Employee (Name, Surname, IdentificationNumber)
VALUES (@Name, @Surname, @IdentificationNumber);
END
SET @NewData =(SELECT    *FROM    EmployeeWHERE    IdentificationNumber = @IdentificationNumber FOR JSON AUTO );
SET @EmpId = (Select    EmployeeIDFrom    EmployeeWHERE    IdentificationNumber = @IdentificationNumber );
INSERT INTO Logs (Type,ProcessTime,EmployeeID,UserId,NewData,Description )
VALUES ('Import Excel',getdate(),@EmpId,1,@NewData,'Successfuly' );
END TRY BEGIN CATCH INSERT INTO Logs (Type,ProcessTime,EmployeeID,UserId,NewData,Description )
VALUES ('Import Excel',getdate(),@EmpId,1,'Error Data: IdentificationNumber=' + @IdentificationNumber,'Error' );
END CATCH 
Fetch Next From JsonTable Into @Name, @Surname, @IdentificationNumber
End 
Close JsonTable 
Deallocate JsonTable
```

Comment: '''return $this->db->query($query);''' php code

Comment: We will need a [mre] of the problem before we can help you. One line of code does not provide that. See also the [tour] and [ask] for guidance on how to ask a useful question here. Use the "edit" button (at the end of your question under the blue tags) when you're ready to update it. Thanks.

Comment: Probably because this isn't just one statement... you can only run a single statement in PHP unless you'd be using multi_query function (some API like mysqli offer those)

Comment: You likely need to put that into a stored procedure